# how to insert html table data into mysqli database in single command

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am using a HTML table form to collect data from users. The rows of the table can be increased by clicking ADD MORE button or can be decreased by clicking DELETE button. So the number of rows in the table are not fixed for all users. Sometimes it would be only 4 rows, sometimes it can be 12 rows. I am wondering how can i insert all data(rows) in my mysqli database by clicking SUBMIT button just once. you can check my table in below link :

[Demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/topu119/4f26Lwhc/1/)

**my php code:**

```
<?php

    $email = $_SESSION["email"];
    $cell = "Select `cellno` FROM `userreg` WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $cell);
    $cellno = "";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            $cellno = $row["cellno"];
        }
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $fullname = $_SESSION["fullname"];
        $medname = $_POST['medname'];
        $medqty  = $_POST['medqty'];
        $medtype = $_POST['medtype'];
        $num = $_POST['num'];
        $date = date("Y.m.d");


      $medorder = "INSERT INTO `medorder` (`fullname`, `phoneno`, `medname`, `quantity`, `medtype`, `date`,`orderno` ) VALUES ('$fullname', '$cellno', '$medname','$medqty', '$medtype', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$num' )";

      if($conn->query($medorder)=== TRUE) 
      {
        echo"<br>";
        echo " Your Question has been submitted successfully";
      }
      else 
      {
        echo " Error!! Try again or later";
      }

    }     
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Change the names of your inputs:

```
   <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD><input type="hidden" value="1" name="num[]" id="orderdata">1</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="medname[]" class="form-control" id="orderdata" placeholder="Your Medicine name"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="medqty[]" class="form-control" id="orderdata" placeholder="Quantity" /></TD>
        <TD>
           <SELECT name="medtype[]" class="form-control" id="orderdata">
              <OPTION value="in">Bangladesh</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
              <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
          </TD>
      </TR>
```

Then built your query by looping throught number of rows in the table.

```
$medorder='';
    foreach ($medname as $key => $value) {
         $medorder .= "INSERT INTO `medorder` (`fullname`, `phoneno`, `medname`, `quantity`, `medtype`, `date`,`orderno` ) VALUES ('$fullname', '$cellno[$key]', '$medname[$key]','$medqty[$key]', '$medtype[$key]', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$num' ),";
}
```